# Transfer file from android device to android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application

Hey is there a way to get the android app from the device to android studio, so I can look at the source code and furthermore install it on a different device from the android studio itself.

This app is on playstore but only on my office device, i can't see it on my personal phone. I tried getting the link but it says "Item not found" on my phone.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `.apk` file from the app you downloaded and decompile it with one of the many available tools online to get the Java bytecode. Keep in mind though that it may be hard to decipher it if the developer has obfuscated his app with something like ProGuard.

The `.apk` itself should be located in one of the following:

```
/data/app
/data/app-private
/system/app/
/sdcard/.android_secure (shows .asec files, not .apks)
/sdcard/external_sd/.android_secure
```